# How to export data edited by gsub

Tags: r, gsub

So I recently learned about `gsub` and I think it can do wonders for me but I am a bit confused about it. I think I am just inexperienced using it. I had a bunch of scripts that I want to run on a cluster, but the format for the job being submitted is specific. So I want to edit the "master" script using `gsub` or similar packages. However, when I run `gsub`, it changes the structure of my data. I will give an example below.

Here is an example of my df. Let me know if you have issues recreating this, I had to play with the `dput` output a bit.

`dput(df)`

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("#!/bin/bash", "#BSUB -W 2880", "#BSUB -n 8", "#BSUB -R span[ptile=8]", "#BSUB -o limaout.%J.txt", "#BSUB -e limaerr.%J.txt", "", "export PATH=$/bin:$PATH", "source activate anaCogent5.2", "", "lima /cell1.ccs.bam /primers.fasta /cell1.removed.ccs.bam --isoseq --no-pbi", "", "#BSUB -J lima.cell1")),
                .Names = "V1",
                row.names = c(NA, -13L),
                class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I run the following gsub to change the parts of the script that I need to change

```
df <- gsub("cell1.ccs.bam", "cell2.ccs.bam", df)
df <- gsub("primers.fasta", "primers2.fasta", df)
df <- gsub("cell1.removed.ccs.bam", "cell2.removed.ccs.bam", df)
df <- gsub("#BSUB -J lima.cell1", "#BSUB -J lima.cell2", df)
```

However, gsub changes my data frame into a value (if that makes sense? I am using Rstudio and that what it changes the `df` to). when I run the following

`df <- as.data.frame(df)`

The correct substitutions were made but the data is no longer in the correct format. It looks like this. Sorry, this isn't in the `dput` format. The data get put in a format that `dput` doesn't seem to like

```
"c(\"#!/bin/bash\", \"#BSUB -W 2880\", \"#BSUB -n 8\", \"#BSUB -R span[ptile=8]\", \"#BSUB -o limaout.%J.txt\", \"#BSUB -e limaerr.%J.txt\", \"\", \"export PATH=$/bin:$PATH\", \"source activate anaCogent5.2\", \"\", \"lima /cell2.ccs.bam /primers2.fasta /cell2.removed.ccs.bam --isoseq --no-pbi\", \"\", \"#BSUB -J lima.cell2\")"
```

Am I using `gsub` correctly? Or are there better packages to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` is great! Glad you're learning it.

What's going on right now is that your data is being converted to a string. If you run `class(df)` after your current `gsub` code, you'll see that it's been converted to a `character` (i.e. a string).

What I suggest is looping over each row in V1 and applying your `gsub` alterations on it. It's not the fastest way, but it'll get the job done:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,'V1'] <- gsub("cell1.ccs.bam", "cell2.ccs.bam", df[i,'V1'])
  df[i,'V1'] <- gsub("primers.fasta", "primers2.fasta", df[i,'V1'])
  df[i,'V1'] <- gsub("cell1.removed.ccs.bam", "cell2.removed.ccs.bam", df[i,'V1'])
  df[i,'V1'] <- gsub("#BSUB -J lima.cell1", "#BSUB -J lima.cell2", df[i,'V1'])
}
```

Comment: This is perfect!! I just starting using for loops as well. This is very exciting!!